# Copying PublishingPage

Tags: publishing-page, publishing

I was wondering what's the best way to copy a PublishingPage that will preserve the webparts, but also, if this base PublishingPage I have, contains a document library, how can I ensure that, the document library for each copied publishing page is unique, i.e. it's not a shared document library?

Thanks for everyone's help.

Comment: To start with: Libraries are in no way connected to Page Layouts. What you are talking about is the webpart displaying content from the library on the page layout.

Comment: So when you add a document library web part to a page, the uploaded documents aren't specific for that page, but on a site level, and just filtered out?

Comment: The libraries live at Web level

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Manage Content and Structure interface to move complete publishing pages.  You access this from the Site Actions menu.

However, if you have a list/library web part in the page and you move it to another site you risk corrupting the source list/library so be careful you only move pages with these web parts within the same site.

Comment: I should of been more clear, I'm asking from a coding point of view, sorry about that, I've been trying to find some API's that can permit the copying of an existing publishing page that I can then modify it's existing web parts and update it's search query for example.

Comment: Ah OK - not my area - good luck.